# RegEx match const followed by alphanumeric string and whitespace

Tags: regex

I have the following string "Code: XX11418328" embedded in a large document.

I'm trying to match the "XX11418328" part, which is any alphanumeric characters, and it ends with a space, or other whitespace.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with case insensitive flag

```
/(?<=Code:\s)[A-Z0-9]+/i
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/tS6dJ0/1)

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: don't forget to accept it if it works for you and BTW, glad to have helped you :)